# android tag editor

Tags: android, mobile

It is my first time building an android app. Was wondering firstly, if there are demos that exists which could help me to build a media tag editor (form to edit mp3 files). 
I would also like to know how to populate the sd card on the emulator.
Any help on android would be good. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your AVD you can tell it how big you want the memory card to be and then you can use DDMS to copy files over to it.  There are pretty good explanations on how to do this on the Android website.

Comment: I have followed a few examples I have seen from the Android site. I have used three methods. I tried the DDMS, adb push method and tried it from the file explorer view that I set up in the eclipse perspective I am using. Sadly none works... I figure it may have something to do with read write access to the sdcard, but this seems a bit odd to me. From file explorer it says that my permissions to the sdcard is 'd---rwxr-x'. Everytime I try to push it on it says that it timed out.

Comment: If you can see it in FileExplorer it means that you have it mounted as an flash drive and you can just copy files over to it.  If you don't have it mounted you can use DDMS.

Comment: I finally got it. I used the adb push method, the difference is that I set the actual file location. eg.
    adb push z:\file.mp3 /sdcard/file.mp3
with the slashes placed appropriately for windows and linux usage. I always left off the file.mp3 from the /sdcard/file.mp3 section. Hope this is actually what I did :)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to extract info from the mp3 files I just pushed on? Not seeing anything of the sort in there documentation so far...